# Android- FragmentTransaction.replace() works only once

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer along with a `SwipeRefreshLayout` for the main content and when the user selects a menu item in the navigation drawer, I want to replace the fragment inside the `SwipeRefreshLayout` with another fragment.

This is what my `onNavigationItemSelected()` looks like:

```
// Handle navigation view item clicks here.
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
selectedNavItem = item.getItemId();

if(selectedNavItem == R.id.nav_files){
    filesFragment = new FilesFragment();
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.swipeLayout,filesFragment,"files");
    transaction.commit();

} else if(selectedNavItem == R.id.nav_accounts){
    accountsFragment = new AccountsFragment();
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.swipeLayout,accountsFragment,"accounts");
    transaction.commit();
}
return true;
```

But this never works. When I click an item in the nav drawer, the fragment is replaced by a blank screen. My `onCreate` method also uses `FragmentTransaction.replace()` but that seems to work fine.

I also tried `FragmentTransaction.remove()` and then `FragmentTransaction.add()` but even that doesn't seem to work.

Edit: Layout files:

Layout of the content view of the navigation drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.harshallele.cloudpool.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout">


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is included inside another layout file which contains a `CoordinatorLayout` containing the toolbar.That file, in turn, is inside the main layout file of the activity inside a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

(Basically, this is the Navigation Drawer Activity provided by Android Studio when adding an Activity)

Layout for `FilesFragment`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.FilesFragment">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fileListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/itemsLoadingProgress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Layout for `AccountsFragment`(this is just the default blank fragment, because i haven't finished this yet):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.harshallele.cloudpool.fragments.AccountsFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Edit 2:

AccountsFragment:

```
public class AccountsFragment extends Fragment {


    public AccountsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your XML please.

Comment: @Bryan added xml files

Comment: Post one of your `AccountsFragment` class as well. I see one issue so far, but I don't think it explains why your fragments would not be displaying.

Comment: Also, just a tip; when pasting code, make sure the entire block of code is highlighted, then hit the `{}` button in the editor. Don't just put four spaces before the first and last line of code.

Comment: @Bryan added  `AccountsFragment` class

Comment: add  navigation drawer xml file

Answer (score 0):

With just this bit of code we can't help you so much. The problem can be that:

1. The `FilesFragment` and `AccountsFragment` aren't initialized in the right way;
2. The `Layout` with id `swipeLayout` can have `visibility = gone`;
3. The `Layout` of `FilesFragment` and `AccountsFragment` can be empty;

This are just some of the infinite reason why your code doesn't work properly so please share more code about the two `Fragments` and relative `XML`.

Comment: If the question is lacking in detail, and has multiple potential causes, its a little premature to post an answer. Wait for the OP to provide more information, then create a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Added layout files and AccountsFragment